# Is it possible to set specific VueRouter props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-router

Working with VueRouter, I want to enable entrance to these URLs:

- `category/apple`
- `category/banana`
- `category/pear`

Is it possible to limit a router parameter so certain strings? (banana, apple, pear)?

I cannot find anything in the documentation specifically about this. and I googled to find some other solutions that do not work:

```
{
    path:       'category/:categoryType',
    props:      true, 
    /*props: {
        validator: function (value) {
            return ( value === 'banana' || value === 'apple' || value === 'pear');
        }
    },*/
    component:  someComponent
},
```

The only solution I can think of right now is to validate this in the `created()` within the component.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is the solution of your case:

```
const allowedCategoryNames = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'];
const categoryRoutePath = '/category/:categoryName(' + allowedCategoryNames.join('|') + ')';
{
    path:       categoryRoutePath,
    props:      true,
    component:  someComponent
},
```

and in your component you can get current cutegory name like this:

```
const currentCategory = this.$route.params.categoryName;
```

That should work =)
Some examples can be found here: [vue-router regexp examples](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js)

Comment: If you set the `props: true` then the route parameters can be accessible with `this.categoryName`.

Comment: can't I just add the whole `categoryRoutePath` variable as a string under `path:` ? Why is it necessary to set it inside a variable? (haven't tested this yes, afk).

Comment: @wellhellothere, I have tested the code above =) Of course, you just can add a string literal instead of variable, but if you extend the list of category names you'll need to edit the route path. Anyways, you can replace `path: categoryRoutePath` with `path: '/category/:categoryName(apple|banana|pear)'`.